# Идентификация данных с использованием не числовых типов данных

Tags: c++, числа

Добрый день. У меня сложный и запутанный вопрос. Хочу услышать научные термины, которые определяют эту особенность данных, то есть как это правильно называется.

```
int a = 1;
int b = 2;
```

числа a и b можно сравнить на равно и на больше меньше и они будут возвращать правильные результаты. Это числовой тип данных.

```
// всегда return вернет корректное значение не зависимо от значений a и b
if(a != b){return a < b;}
```

А например данные такого типа,

```
std::map<int , bool> a;
std::map<int , bool> b;
```

где a равно b если любой ключ a или b есть и у другой переменной.
Соответственно a не равно b если у них нет ни одного общего ключа.

```
bool operator==(std::map<int , bool> A,std::map<int , bool> B)
{
    for (auto ИТ = A.begin(); ИТ != A.end(); ИТ++) {
        if (B.count(ИТ -> first) > 0) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Но запись

```
if(a != b){return a < b;}
```

не будет давать правильный результат, так как a и b можно сравнивать только на равно или не равно. В них нет понятия больше или меньше. Это не числовой тип данных. И использовать эту конструкцию в качестве ключа std::map<> нельзя так как это может повредить структуру данных дерева std::map.

Поэтому должен существовать научный термин который вставляется вместо X.

Переменные

```
int a = 1; 
int b = 2;
```

*являются **...X...** поэтому их можно сравнивать на равно не равно, больше меньше.*
Они могут использоваться для идентификации уникальных данных.

Переменные

```
std::map<int , bool> a;
std::map<int , bool> b;
```

*не являются **...X...** поэтому их можно сравнивать только на равно и не равно.*
Они не могут использоваться для идентификации уникальных данных.

Мне нужно знать, что вставляется вместо метки **...X...**, когда требуется объяснить почему нельзя использовать такой тип данных переменных в std::map для определения уникальной структуры. То есть можно сказать, эти типы можно привести к числу, а эти нет, только как правильно выразиться.

Comment: >Они не могут/не могут использоваться для идентификации уникальных данных.

А какое отношение сравнение на больше-меньше имеет к идентификации уникальных данных? Думается, никакого.

Comment: Ну алгоритмы поиска в структурах(в частности std::map) используют числа и требуют проверки на больше меньше в некоторых операциях, поэтому и спрашиваю.

Comment: Элементы множества могут быть уникальными, но это не значит, что для них обязательно определены операции сравнения на больше-меньше.

Comment: @klopp 
Ну имеется ввиду по отношению к контейнеру std::map. Для элементов обязательно должны быть определены операции сравнения на больше меньше, чтобы можно было быстро найти элементы. А для идентификации да, не обязательно.

Comment: @manking, вообще-то для *множеств* операции больше-меньше как раз необязательны.

Достаточно операции **равно**.

Вспомнните о хэш-таблицах.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Думаю, то что Вы ищите, называется [Линейно упорядоченное множество](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9B%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%BE_%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%BE) - для этого множества определены операции сравнения для любых двух его элементов.

Comment: Спасибо.
Думаю да это то.

То есть можно сказать, что любой тип данных который передаётся  в качестве ключа в std::map должен быть линейно упорядоченным множеством, иначе будут выскакивать ошибки invalid operator< и структура контейнера станет не валидной?

Comment: думаю правильно сказать так - в качестве ключа может быть *любой тип, для которого можно определить компаратор* (то есть функцию, которая будет сравнивать на больше-меньше-равно). Вполне возможно, что Вы сможете написать компаратор для своих данных, которые не являются упорядоченным множеством в математическом смысле.

Кстати, в с++ операция равно часто определяется как `!(a<b) && !(b<a)`, хотя с математической точки зрения это не является линейно упорядоченным множеством)